# Fourier cosine series of even periodic extension

Tags: fourier-analysis

I've been posed the following question:
[screenshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krW9j.png)

I have tried using the formula for the Fourier series of an even function but don't think this is the correct approach. I have tried looking over my lecture notes and examples but I am not sure where to begin.

Any suggestions, help or answers will be **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Remember that the extension will have a period of $2\pi$ not $\pi$ when you find the Fourier cosine coefficients.